# PyQGIS - assign points to polygons in variable number

Tags: pyqgis

In a low-income neighborhood in Argentina several families may share a dwelling.
I have a vector layer with numerous dwellings (adjoining polygons) and a table with a field indicating number of families per dwelling. Task is to automatically plot as many points as individual families share each dwelling (polygon).
As a first approximation I have tried to do this using the native:randompointsinpolygons algorithm. See code below.
It plots points but only those read in last. I presume the solution may be either to sequentially select each dwelling and apply the algorithm to the selected feature, and then save the result, or to move the OUTPUT outside the loop, save each result in memory, and save results at the end

[image].

But I do not know how to do it. The attached image shows the setting.

```
viviendas = iface.activeLayer()
#print(viviendas.fields().names())

for f in viviendas.getFeatures():
    num_flia = f.attributes()[5]
    m = f.attributes()[1]
    i = f.id()
    print(i,m,num_flia)
    viviendas.select(i)
    res = processing.run("native:randompointsinpolygons",{
        'INPUT': viviendas,
        'POINTS_NUMBER':num_flia,
        'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/Gustavo GB/Documents/Mi_proyecto/r11.shp'})
        
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer('C:/Users/Gustavo GB/Documents/Mi_proyecto/r11.shp',
               'Resultado', 'ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange, Gustavo. I've a request for clarification: do you want random points in the final result? Or would you prefer a different solution? Is the goal to have a point layer fur further analysis or are the points just there for as a visualization tool?

Comment: Hello underdark, You hit the nail on the head! The problem is more complex (at least it is for me) and I was trying to tackle it in steps. Each dwelling contains a specified number of families (points). Additionally, each point should link to family attributes, such as income, number of sons, read from a table. In the end, the social worker will click a point in the QGIS canvas and recover certain data regarding that family. Perhaps assign a particular color if a certain condition is met, for instance having more than 3 sons. I don't expect to get a full solution, simply some pointers. Cheers

Comment: Your question is still unclear for me. Though, check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this script.

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
crs = lyr.crs().authid()

# append new fields you want (check and edit/append &field=field_name:field_type)
uri = f"Point?crs={crs}&field=id:integer"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "Points", "memory")

vlayer.startEditing()

for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    num_flia = f["num_flia"]
    i = f.id()
    g = f.geometry()
    
    points = g.randomPointsInPolygon(num_flia)    
    for point in points:        
        feat = QgsFeature(vlayer.fields())
        feat["id"] = i
        geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(point)
        feat.setGeometry(geom)
        vlayer.addFeature(feat)
    
vlayer.commitChanges()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

This is a minimal example. You need to improve it to suit your needs.